# How to show various layout at each swipe

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

in my application which implements swipe ,, i have been used the fragment ,, but it work on one layout with various title for tabs ,, can i implements it using multiple layouts
 this is my code what are the changes must i include in my code to show in every section different layout

```
 package net.justanotherblog.swipeview;

  import java.util.Locale;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
  import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.view.Gravity;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

 }
```

Comment: So you have to add different fragments in your existing code now you only have one fragment.

Comment: mmmm i'm new in android so i don't understand what u mean exactly,, please any help with apeice of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    package net.justanotherblog.swipeview;

      import java.util.Locale;

      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
      import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
      import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
      import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
      import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
      import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
      import android.view.Gravity;
      import android.view.LayoutInflater;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.ViewGroup;
      import android.widget.TextView;

     public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the app.
       List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentThree.class.getName()));
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentFour.class.getName()));
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentFive.class.getName()));
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSix.class.getName()));

mSectionsPagerAdapter=newSectionsPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

//





    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                     int _pos = position % 6;
                     return fragments.get(_pos);

                }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

     }
```

like this you can add n number of `Fragments` in your `viewpager`.

Answer (score 0):

Hin

You can use an array whit your layout id and when you make right swipe add + 1 or if you make left swpie substract -1.

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;


int[] values = new int[] {
            R.id.layout1,
            R.id.Layout2,
            R.id.Layout3 };

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {

        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
                return false;
            }

            /**
             * left to right swipe
             */
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                //next layout       
                setContentView(values +1);


                /**
                 * right to left
                 */
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {


                    //prev layout
                    setContentView(values -1);

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: and if each section of layouts have its code where i can implement?/